# Trailing Slash tool in CherryPy 3.2 not adding a trailing slash

Tags: python, routes, cherrypy, trailing-slash

I cannot get the trailing_slash tool to work. I've played around with
the options for the trailing_slash tool and nothing seems to have any effect.
I am using CherryPy 3.2.2 and Routes 1.13. I would like to have a
trailing slash added. There is no errors in the debug output.

If I go to 127.0.0.1:8080/blog/ it works, however if I go
to 127.0.0.1:8080/blog it doesn't.

My Configuration is:

```
conf = {
'/': {
    'request.dispatch': setup_routes(),
    # This trailing slash stuff has no effect :(
    'tools.trailing_slash.on': True,
    'tools.trailing_slash.missing': True,
    'tools.trailing_slash.status': 301,
},
'/static': {
       'tools.staticdir.on': True,
       'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
       'tools.staticdir.dir': 'static'
   }
}
```

And the example route is:

```
routes = [["blog_index", "/blog/", {'controller': BlogController(), 'action': 'index','entry_id': 'index'}],]
```

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong? Is there a bug or lack of
essential documentation? Does the trailing_slash tool work with the Routes Dispatcher?

The full src: https://bitbucket.org/ddevine/icdy/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing slash Tool doesn't work with the Routes Dispatcher. The trailing slash tool expects that whatever dispatcher is chosen will set `cherrypy.request.is_index` to True or False, which it looks like the `RoutesDispatcher` class doesn't do at all. Therefore, `is_index` is left at None, and the trailing slash Tool does nothing. It might be possible for someone with a good knowledge of Routes to fix that in the CherryPy codebase, or write their own dispatcher which sets is_index, or try to write another Tool which fixes up is_index after the fact.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Looks like I will be writing a custom dispatcher then. Hopefully I do not find more undocumented goodies when attempting to do so.

Comment: I had a look into the code. After `result = self.mapper.match(path_info)` in the RoutesDispatcher find_handler I put:
    if result == None:
        result = self.mapper.match(path_info+"/")`
This seems to work, though it may be a very silly thing to do for reasons I am unaware of yet.

Comment: @DanielDevine you probably don't want to do that because a path with a trailing slash and one without can do very different things in Routes. It's not a good idea if you want to ensure correctness. It's better to configure your reverse proxy web server to add a slash to whatever paths where you want one.

Answer (score 1):

Long time asked, but here is a way to make it work:

```
def index(index=True):
    cherrypy.request.is_index = index
cherrypy.tools.index = cherrypy.Tool('on_start_resource', index)

config = {
    ...
        'tools.trailing_slash.status': 307,
        'tools.index.on': True,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no notion of an "index" in Routes because you can define 2 connections of the same path, one with a trailing slash and one without, and have them connected to 2 completely different controllers and/or actions. You won't do this in real life, but it's possible in Routes, so there's really not a good way to change the trailing_slash tool to deal with this.

IMHO, the trailing_slash tool is a bit lacking and it should probably be elevated to the level of a WSGI middleware that sits in front of the default WSGI middle pipeline, like the InternalRedirect middleware is doing in CherryPy now. For example, if you've mounted a RouteDispatcher under a script_name, you can't put the trailing_slash tool anywhere to have CP put a trailing slash after the script_name because all the routes in Routes must start with a slash, and it will throw a RoutesException if the path_info is an empty string when you try to match.